# Dplyr Package: Merge Variables

Tags: r, dplyr

There are 2 relevant variables in my dataset that I want to merge to a new variable:

car = factor:

1. has electric car
2. has petrol car

payment = factor:

1. paid for car in cash
2. paid for car using bank transfer
3. paid using other methods

I am trying to create a new variable that takes on the values of the variable payment only if "has electric car" is true.

How can I do that using "dplyr" package?

Thanks!

Reproducible Example:

```
data <-  data.frame(car = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE),
                    payment = sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: what is your expected output for this data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
df <- data %>%  mutate(new_var = ifelse(car == 1, payment, NA))
```